# Power Query - Change Column Type IF Text contains formula

Tags: excel, powerbi, powerquery

i have a report that always includes the last 36 months. I want to change the data type of these 36 months to currency, instead of the current type text. Is there a way to not solve this by not hardcoding it?

For example, change all columns that have this format XXXX/XX.

[image]

Comment: Doo they always appear in the same location in the report - eg the last 36 columns?

Comment: yes, they are always in the same position

Comment: Then you could use `List.Range` with `Table.ColumnNames` in a similar manner to horseyride's solution below.

Answer (score 1):

To change format of last 36 columns in Powerquery:

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
Change =  Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(List.LastN(Table.ColumnNames(Source),36), each {_, Currency.Type}))
in Change
```

Or you can try something like this which searches and changes all columns containing a /

```
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],

 Change =  Table.TransformColumnTypes(
  Source,
  List.Transform(
      List.FindText(
          Table.ColumnNames(Source),
          "/"
      ),
  each {_, Currency.Type}
  )
)
in x
```

to mask out XXX/XX you'd need to overlay some regex code on top of it